# ctree plot decision tree in party package in R , terminal node occurs some weird numbers - issue?

Tags: r, plot, modeling, decision-tree

I came across something really odd.. and I couldn't figured it out why..

I use the same code here below :

```
library(party)
r_tree <- ctree(readingSkills$nativeSpeaker ~ readingSkills$age + 
                 readingSkills$shoeSize + readingSkills$shoeSize + 
                 readingSkills$score,data = readingSkills)
plot(r_tree,type = "simple")
r_tree
```

two week ago I got normal graph .. but today my terminal nodes have some odd numbers in them like showing in this picture below.. I have tried to restarted my PC , uninstalled the packet , reinstall again and again , but it still not working.. 
[image]
Just wondering if anyone see the same issue , or what have I done wrong , or how can I fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by odd? the numbers are nor rounded? the picture  is not clear.

Comment: Hi agstudy , sorry for the late reply didn't see your comment. well, the Gray Boxes , some showing as text " Terminal node" , somes showing 0,0,0,0 ..  and some showing some real number like 0.1254635654151 , 1032165465131321   ??

Comment: in what basis `ctree` splits the data? What method does it follow (Gini split or other), Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug caused by package "partykit". If you'll reopen R from start or do:

`detach("package:partykit", unload=TRUE)` and run

```
library(party)
r_tree <- ctree(readingSkills$nativeSpeaker ~ readingSkills$age + 
                  readingSkills$shoeSize + readingSkills$shoeSize + 
                  readingSkills$score,data = readingSkills)
plot(r_tree,type = "simple")
```

You'll get the normal plot
[image]

But if you'll library the "partykit" package again and rerun the same code, you''ll get that nonsense plot again

```
library(partykit)
r_tree <- ctree(readingSkills$nativeSpeaker ~ readingSkills$age + 
                  readingSkills$shoeSize + readingSkills$shoeSize + 
                  readingSkills$score,data = readingSkills)
plot(r_tree,type = "simple")
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Hi Dave, can you provide a source for this? I searched for the solution but couldn't find anything. Or did you come up with this yourself? But thanks anyway

Comment: Hi Raffael, I came up with it myself long ago... My solution is just detach partykit whenever you need a normal plot, or just not to use partykit at all. I never use partykit because I've created my own plot for ctree package, which makes the lines thicker by volume and gives different colors to the buckets by Converion rate, score or what so ever. I can share the code and show you an example if you want...

Comment: so the plot.ctree function is overloaded in partykit and buggy there. so far all plots I made using party::plot.ctree() have been alright.

Comment: That's also a solution :)