# R: party package, ctree output - err?

Tags: r, decision-tree

What does the statistics/number 'err' mean in ctree's output? How to retrive test statistic/p-value on the base of which the coovariate are being chosen? Thanks.

```
Model formula:
Dis ~ score_final

Fitted party:
[1] root
|   [2] score_final <= 521
|   |   [3] score_final <= 445: 0.512 (n = 123, err = 30.7)
|   |   [4] score_final > 445: 0.358 (n = 684, err = 157.2)
|   [5] score_final > 521: 0.253 (n = 1369, err = 258.6)

Number of inner nodes:    2
Number of terminal nodes: 3
```

Comment: This looks like `partykit` rather than `party` to me

Comment: also, what is the structure of your data? Can you provide a `str(df)`? Also, please provide the plot

Comment: Thanks. It was partykit responsible for this kind of output. One more question: Do you know why party::ctree and partykit::ctree give different results?

Comment: Because they are different packages. Each one of them has it's own thing. I don't think this output You've got from `partykit` is wrong, you just need to learn how to read it. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781349/ctree-plot-decision-tree-in-party-package-in-r-terminal-node-occurs-some-weird/22554710#22554710) if you have issues with your plot

Comment: Yes, they are different packages, but they implement the same algorithm, don't they? Which one better to use ?

Comment: It depends on your needs. `partykit` is more "do-it-your-way" package, while `party` does everything for you. I always use `party` as I have no patience for all the new anses in `partykit`, but you should decide for yourself I guess